# sata hdd not recognized after installation with nvme

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, nvme

Symptom: In Bios, CSM Support: Complete installation with UEFI in Disabled state ->  Symptom that HDD installed in sata is not recognized after installing Ubuntu in nvme

(Recognized without any problem on Windows or Windows PE)

```
lshw -C disk
```

or

```
fdisk -l
```

or

```
/dev/sd*
```

The status itself is not recognized at all.

Comment: This kind of problem is common when you have Windows installed in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in legacy mode. You appear to have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode and it’s unlikely Windows is not UEFI. Where is Windows installed? I assume you have 1 SSD and one nvme drive

Comment: @PonJar It's not that Windows os is installed on the additional disk, but I wrote it to check whether Windows recognizes it normally when recognizing it (there is no problem with disk recognition).

Comment: I'll go home and check what you told me.

Comment: Not recognized after installing ubuntu or not recognized after installing NVME? I don't know your level of expertise, but there is a lot of research necessary about how your hardware works/conflicts/shares/disables when using M2/nvme/SATA/PCIE mixtures. For example, if I use my second NVME, I lose the use of 2 specific SATA connectors on my motherboard. On some boards, some things share "lanes" and disable each other. You may end up consulting your motherboard's manual(and google)... I still haven't gotten all of the terminology or nuances straight yet.